# Downloading file with SharePoint API: file damaged

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, inputstream

I'm developing a Java library for basic operations on SharePoint using Graph API.

I make a call on this entry point using SOAP UI:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/content
```

And I obtain a raw response:

```
%PDF-1.6
%âãÏÓ

1751 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/First 98/Length 322/N 11/Type/ObjStm>>stream

hÞœÔ½J1†á[ÉL’ó“–m,md±ÁElTü)¼{3“wXYDØ©¾3!ç<)&I^kˆ!ymÁ¤gë¥ÍE ...
endstream
endobj
startxref
2993893
%%EOF
```

It look like i'm retrieving an input stream.
In the HttpRequest class I try to build a response object that returns the InputStream. My property fileInputStream is an InputStream:

```
SharePointDownloadResponseModel returnValue = new SharePointDownloadResponseModel();
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
returnValue.setFileInputStream(inputStream);
return returnValue;
```

Now in my manager class I try to save the input stream in the hard drive. I handle 2 cases. First case, I have a fileName a folder to store the file. My request object  :

```
if(request.getDownloadFolder() != null && request.getFileName() !=null) {
   InputStream initialStream = returnValue.getFileInputStream();
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(request.getDownloadFolder() + "/" + request.getFileName());
   BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos );

   // Read bytes from URL to the local file
   byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
   int bytesRead = 0;

   System.out.println("Downloading " + request.getFileName());
   while ((bytesRead = initialStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
       bos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
   }

   bos.flush();
   // Close destination stream
   bos.close();
   // Close URL stream
   initialStream.close();
}
```

The document is created where it should be created but the file is damaged and can't be opened. I wonder what is the issue at this stage.

Comment: Try repro the issue with same API call with POSTMAN/MS Graph Explorer to see if you can still repro the issue or not.

Comment: My issue is not Postman issue and can't be reproduced.. In SOAP UI / Postman I retrieve a raw stream as response. My issue is to pass this stream as object value and to convert it into file.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my issue. Here is a basic method that shows my implementation :

```
public class DownloadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/content";
        SharePointCredentialRequest sharePointCredentialRequest = new SharePointCredentialRequest(Constants.TENANT_CLIENT_ID,
                Constants.TENANT_CLIENT_SECRET, Constants.TENANT_AUTHORITY);

        String token = Utils.getToken(sharePointCredentialRequest);
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet)) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                System.out.println(response.getAllHeaders().length);
                System.out.println(entity.getContentEncoding());
                System.out.println(entity.getContentLength());
                System.out.println(entity.getContentType().getElements().toString());

                try  {
                    // do something useful with the stream
                    InputStream inputStream = IOUtils.toBufferedInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
                    File targetFile = new File("C:\\myFolder\\kant.pdf");
                    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, targetFile);
                } catch (IOException | UnsupportedOperationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you share the implementation of this class. SharePointCredentialRequest sharePointCredentialRequest = new SharePointCredentialRequest(Constants.TENANT_CLIENT_ID,
                Constants.TENANT_CLIENT_SECRET, Constants.TENANT_AUTHORITY);

Comment: The implementation of this class totally changed in 2 years. I can't share it, it won't have any sense because of updates. Sorry